# Why do I get this "input_shape error"? (python keras)

Tags: python, keras

```
Using TensorFlow backend.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/hjkim/.conda/envs/hjkim/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:64: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lstm.py", line 51, in <module>
    model = lstm()
  File "lstm.py", line 22, in lstm
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(400, input_shape = (None, ), return_sequences = True)))
  File "/home/hjkim/.conda/envs/hjkim/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 451, in add
    raise ValueError('The first layer in a '
ValueError: The first layer in a Sequential model must get an `input_shape` or `batch_input_shape` argument.
```

This is the script I've got, and I know that the last sentence is the error.
But, I thought I've set my input_shape properly.

Actually, it worked well with the keras version 2.3.1, but I downgraded it to 2.1.2 due to some other ValueError problems.

I want to solve this problem, but I could not do it with myself.. please someone help me. Let me know what I have missed.

Comment: Please include the part of the code that throws this error.

Comment: I've solved the problem by myself. Thank you!